# Normal subgroup acting on a set

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, normal-subgroups

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $X$ and let $S \lhd G$. Determine the necessary and sufficient conditions so that there exists an action of $G/S$ on $X$ such that $\overline{a}.x=a.x$ for all $a \in G$ and $x \in X$.

I am pretty much stuck with this exercise, I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: try explaining your first two or three steps...

Comment: Well, I know that if $G/S$ is acting on $X$, then 1) $\overline{e}.x=x$ for all $x \in X$ 2) $\overline{a}.(\overline{b}.x)=\overline{ab}.x$ for all $\overline{a},\overline{b} \in G/S$,$x \in X$. I don't know what restrictions (necessary conditions) I can deduce from here.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this notation - what is $\overline a$ supposed to mean in this context?

Comment: It means the coset $aS$

Comment: @user16924 Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.  Think about what it would mean for the given action ($\bar{a}\cdot x = a\cdot x$) to be well-defined.  That means that, whenever $\bar{a}=\bar{b}$, for $a,b\in G$, you must have $\bar{a}\cdot x = \bar{b}\cdot x$, for all $x$ in $X$.

Comment: Well, if I choose two different representatives $a,a' \in G$ of $\overline{a}$, then we must have $\overline{a}.x=\overline{a'}.x$ if and only if $a.x=a'.x$ I suppose this doesn't necessary imply $a=a'$.

Comment: It only means all the elements from the same coset must be sent to the same element from $Sym(X)$, right?

Comment: If $\bar{a}=\bar{b}$ then $aS = bS$ (and conversely). To have the action of $G/S$ be well-defined, you need to have $\bar{a}\cdot x = \bar{b}\cdot x$ for *all* $x$, which, by definition, means that $a\cdot x = b\cdot x$, for *all* $x$.  Try to connect these up.

Comment: See the comment I made below Praphulla's answer

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but a few minutes ago I tried to think the problem again and I think that the necessary and sufficient condition would be that: if $\phi$ is the morphism from $G$ to $X$, then $Ker(\phi)=S$-

Comment: @user16924, Almost.  (Well, first, I suppose you meant that $\phi$ is a morphism from $G$ to $Sym(X)$?) You don't quite need equality; it is enough that $S$ is contained in the kernel of $\phi$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $Sym(X)$. I could finish the problem, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Checking conditions of  Group action  does not say much as it is natural..

$\overline{ab}\cdot x=ab\cdot x=a\cdot(b\cdot x)$

$\bar{a}\cdot(\bar{b}\cdot x)=\bar{a}\cdot(b\cdot x)=a\cdot(b\cdot x)$

All that you need to see is does the map makes sense??

I mean is it well defined??

Comment: $G$ acting on $X$ can be seen as a morphism $\phi:G \to Sym(X)$. As you and James suggested, from the well definition one deduces that $G/S$ acts on $X$ if and only if for all $a,b \in G$ : $aRb$ (or $aS=bS$), $\phi(a)=\phi(b)$. Is this correct?

Comment: you are just restating the definition... Take your own time and think what does this imply?

Comment: Yup, I am going to give it a little more thought, I could conclude that $a^{-1}b \in Ker(\phi)$, but I don't know if this says anything really